# After 18.04 update not able to login

Tags: 18.04, login, password-recovery

My laptop got auto update of 18.04.1 from 16.04. After the update, the login tab appears with user name (my name). I can't login because I have no password. I never used password to open my laptop before. How to proceed now?

```
Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS hns-Lenovo tty2
hns-Lenovo login
```

is displayed. I can't login since I have no password.
How to start 18.04 bypassing login?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password

Comment: have you tried booting into recovery mode, then dropping to the root shell, then run the passwd command for your user?

Comment: Not sure myself but, what happens when you simply press `Enter` without entering a password?

Comment: When I simply press Enter the screen goes into booting mode and returns to login display.